# Accessing an outer object from a nested function (Using backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am building a js heavy app using backbone.js.  One problem I've run into a couple of times is how to call an outer object from a deep nested function.  In the code example below, I would like to call the custom_function event when a slide event occurs.  What is the best way to do this?

```
App.Views.Category = Backbone.View.extend({
    ....,
    render: function () {

        $('#slider').slider({
            min:0,
            max:100,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
               //HOW DO I CALL THE custom_function from here????

            },

        });
    },

    custom_function: function() {
       alert('in custom function');
    },


});
```

asdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two common options.

You can either `this` into an object like `that` or `self` then call it.

```
render: function () {
    var that = this;
    $('#slider').slider({
        min:0,
        max:100,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
           //HOW DO I CALL THE custom_function from here????
           that.custom_function();
        },

    });
},
```

Or you can bind the context of the function.

```
render: function () {
    $('#slider').slider({
        min:0,
        max:100,
        slide: (function(event, ui) {
           //HOW DO I CALL THE custom_function from here????
           this.custom_function();
        }).bind(this),

    });
},
```

Function.prototype.bind is ES5 only so use [`_.bind`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bind) or [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy) for cross browser support

Comment: i tried the first approach you had before.  "this" would always give me the "#slider" dom element and "that" would be empty. For the second approach, i get a "handlers.push in not a fucntion" error from jquery.

Comment: @DevX `.bind` only works in chrome/FF3.6+/IE9 so try it in those. What your describing sounds like a really weird bug.

Comment: I'd probably use _.bind for the cross browser support anyways.  What would be the syntax for _.bind in this case?

Comment: @DevX you need to use `this` inside the function in the second example, I fixed that. `_.bind(function, scope)`